# Duda plantilla de funciones

Tags: c++

La duda es clara y concisa, yo tengo una plantilla de función, algo tal que así:

```
template <typename T>
T suma(T& a, T&b)
{
 return a+b;
}
```

La pregunta es, ¿qué tengo que poner para decirle el tipo de datos que recibo?
¿Inmediatamente lo sabe el compilador por el tipo de las variables?
es decir, cuando yo llamo a `suma(3,2)` si 3,2 son enteros, ¿ya lo sabría?
O tendría que decirle de alguna forma que T es un tipo char/int...?

No sé si me explico, si no, ponedme algún comentario y seré más claro.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yo tengo una plantilla de función, algo tal que así:

Pues ya empezamos mal... fíjate que la función tiene como tipo de retorno `void`, cuando debería ser `T`:

```
template <typename T>
T suma(T& a, T&b)
{
 return a+b;
}
```

> ¿qué tengo que poner para decirle el tipo de datos que recibo?

Dado que es una plantilla de función, el compilador será capaz de determinar el tipo automáticamente si ambos parámetros son del mismo tipo:

```
suma(3,4);     // especializado para el tipo int
suma(3.0,4.5); // especializado para double
suma(3,3.5);   // error, int y double ¿cual elegir?
```

Para el resto de casos, como usas referencias, no podrás compilar de ninguna forma (salvo que uses polimorfismo):

```
struct A
{
  A(int valor) : v(valor)
  {}

  int v;
};

struct B : A
{
  B(int valor) : A(valor)
  { }
};

A operator+(A const& a1, A const& a2)
{
  return A(a1.v + a2.v);
}

std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& out, A const& a)
{
  return out << a;
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  std::cout << suma(a,b);
}
```

Aun así verás que el programa sigue sin compilar y esto es porque el compilador no puede decidir si `T` debe ser `A&` o `B&`... por muy compatibles que sean ambos tipos. En este caso la solución pasa por indicar expresamente el tipo de especialización a usar:

```
int main()
{
  A a(2);
  B b(3);
  std::cout << suma<A>(a,b);
  //               ^^^
}
```

Comment: Ya he corregido el gravísimo error de devolver en función void, mis disculpas jejej Gracias @eferion